# What's the need for different ways to represent data using the binary system?

Tags: binary, cpu-architecture, representation, data-representation, ones-complement

There are many ways to represent data using binary like - unsigned, signed magnitude, 1s/2s complement, offset-M,
floating-point, ASCII, and Unicode. Why do we need so many different ways?

Comment: is the data that you are representing all of one type?

Comment: Representations are *interpretations*. Why we have many interpretation of the same number? Because we have different problems.

Comment: We don't.  1's complement and sign/magnitude integers are not used in modern systems, except maybe in some file formats.  And Unicode is a superset of ASCII, so if you decide to use Unicode everywhere, you don't need ASCII anymore.  (Although then all your functions have to handle the general case of Unicode where a character isn't fixed length.)

Comment: It is useful to have efficient fixed-width types, and variable-length arbitrary-precision formats, though.  And to have a text character set so we can print integers into human-readable strings.

Comment: meta question: should [representation] be a synonym of [data-representation] or vice versa?  I didn't previously know either tag existed, but there are similar questions in both.  Someone should ask on meta, I guess, unless there's an existing discussion.  (I'm hoping someone who's seen either of those tags before might post a meta question so I don't have to go digging myself.)